# Integral and hyperbolic/trigonometric substituition

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, substitution

I want to solve the integral $\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}\, dx$. 
I have thought to consider a tranformation of variables: $x=\cosh{t}\implies dx=\sinh{t}$ and so $\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}\, dx=\int\frac{1} {\cosh{t}}\,dt$, then from here I am able to solve the integral.

$\textbf{My question is:}$ It is opportune to use the hyperbolic function in the transformation and NOT for instance $t=\cos{x}$, otherwise I would obtain $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\frac{1}{\cos{x}\sqrt{-\sin^2{x}}}$ and so the square root of a negative object, that it is not defined in the real space, right?

Comment: Easier: let $x=\sec\theta$.

Comment: $x = \cos t$ would definitely be a mistake, yes. I believe the standard transformation here is $x = \sec t$ so that $\sqrt{\sec^2 t - 1} = |\tan t|$, and here I prefer that but your approach  is also valid.

Comment: This is very correct ! (+1)

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestions of other substitution and for confirming the idea of the mistake  that would be committed in case of the trigonometric function!